# Open new tab on div element click with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that supposed to open a link in a new tab once per session when user clicks on a specific class or id of html element. but for some reason it's doesn't work.

```
var clickCounter = 0;
function bodyimgclick(e){
  if( clickCounter == 0 ) {

var homepage = document.querySelector('.post-body img');
    var popUp = function(e) {
      window.open ("http://google.com");
      homepage.removeEventListener('click', popUp, false);
    }

    homepage.addEventListener('click', popUp, false);
 }
  clickCounter++;
}
```

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work" about it?  Is there an error on the debugging console?  Something else?

Comment: link is not open at all

Comment: This would be a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with some debugging tools.  Take a look at the development tools in your web browser.  With them you can check for console errors, place breakpoints in your code and observe the runtime behavior, etc.

Comment: I am familiar and get no errors

Comment: So then what *does* happen?  "It doesn't work" isn't a meaningful description of the problem.  When you step through in the debugger, what *specifically* happens?  Is the target page element found by the selector?  Does the code execute at all?  Does the handler get triggered when you click on the element?  Where exactly does this fail?  You need to do at least *some* debugging here.

Comment: when i debug the only message i can see is "[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 38ms"

Comment: Do you mean that when you debug this code is never even invoked at all?  Well, if nothing is *calling* this function then that would certainly explain why this function "isn't working".  Which would also mean that the problem is somewhere else, unrelated to the code shown here.

Comment: I created code snippet in dev tools and now get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error and nothing  besides that

Answer (score 0):

change window.open ("http://google.com"); window.open('http://google.pl', '_blank');

The additional ('_blank') argument opens a new tab.

Comment: it makes no change